# Ng-repeat and ng-if usage for html td

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I receive a Json that looks like this (I dont have access to change it)

```
{
  "name": "mike"
  "days": [
    {
      "timeperiods": [
        {
          "time": "08:00 - 12:00",
          "hours": 4,
          "task": "running"
        },
        {
           "time": "13:00 - 15:00",
           "hours": 4,
           "task": "triathlon"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
    "timeperiods": [
      {
        "time": "08:00 - 12:00",
        "hours": 3,
        "task": "swimming"
      }
    ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Its not an full JSON-Example. Usually there would be 6 days objects. But i think showing 2 Objects should show my problem.
I create an table in html which shows me what tasks an user has on certain days.
(I save the JSON Data in a scope variable with the name weekplan.)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wedesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="day in weekplan.days[0].timeperiods">
      <td>{{day.time}}</td>
      <td ng-if="day.hours == 0"><div></div></td>
      <td ng-if="day.hours != 999 && day.hours != 0">Time for Workout!!</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It can only be one ng-if true never both.
My Problem is to display the Columns correctly. This table example works but only for the time column and the monday column. But i dont know how to get it to work on all weekdays. I thought about using ng-if and ng-repeat on the same td object but it didnt really work out. (I need both ng-if for CSS rules which i have removed from this example cause its not part of the problem). What i want in the End is a table which either shows an empty field for a certain timeperiod or a field where it says "Time for Workout". And this for all Weekdays.

Comment: This makes little to no sense.  How can time exist in a row alongside a day?  Are you saying that the same time must be used for each day?  I don't think your target table structure is very clear.

Comment: It looks like you're just iterating over the timeperiods in the first day. You want to wrap that in `ng-repeat='D in weekplan.days'`.

Comment: Give us more details about your css rule. I think this will be the key to solve your problem.

Comment: @João Paulo de Lima Thank you for interest but i will delete this question, its badly written and i need to talk to the other developer because with this jsonfile i cant work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have very confusing description, but if logically present your json it will look something like:

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wedesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="day in weekplan.days">
        <td data-ng-repeat="period in day.timeperiods">
          <span>{{day.time}}</span>
          <span ng-if="day.hours == 0"></span> <!-- why it is even exist? -->
          <span ng-if="day.hours != 999 && day.hours != 0">Time for Workout!! </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: this is a nice solution but it doesnt work for me. I Actually need the td element because, based on which ng-if is true, different css rules for the td will apply. I'm sorry if my question is confusing, i removed alot of things from the code before i put it on here to focus on the problem.

Comment: @member2 Maybe you should revised your css rules?